# How to have a stretchy image slider in header of table view like wallapop app

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview

Is there any way to have a stretchy image slider in header of table view like **[wallapop](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/wallapop-buy-sell-nearby/id692753615?mt=8)** app? I found [GSKStretchyHeaderView](https://github.com/gskbyte/GSKStretchyHeaderView) which is great, but work only with one image and I can only use it inside a UIView subclass.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the original author of `GSKStretchyHeaderView`. You can actually put whatever you want inside the stretchy header, actually, you can even load it from a nib, so you can replicate the wallapop header. Have a look at the examples for more hints :)

Comment: I have query on your GSKStretchyHeaderView I have making sticky header but after api call I need to update then sticky header how can do?

Answer (score -2):

UISlider's  minimumValueImage And maximumValueImage can do that ? I have

it can define it by yourself

Comment: Have you seen wallapop app? Did you go to see detail any of ads?